# Bootstrap date time picker not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I have attached all the required libraries to use date time picker, but still it doesn't work. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vs6uzv50/4/)

```
<div class='input-group date' id='from_time'>
     <input type='text' class="form-control input-lg transparent-input" name="to_time" placeholder="To Time" required> 
       <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></span>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#from_time').datetimepicker();
    });
```

Comment: Show how you include library

Comment: @Dest you can check in fiddle, can't you??

Comment: @Leothelion yes i can check there but if you will open console you will see there is some load problem on that page... that's why it does not works there in fiddle

Comment: Well sorry for my words but i don't want to be rude.. Yes that's because https issue which is given in answer below.. Have a Nice Day :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is blocked, because you refer to a different domain with HTTP in an HTTPS connection. Open the browser console, and you'll see.

Use `https` URLs, and it will work. It works [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vs6uzv50/6/).

Comment: Another issue. In mobile view, datetime pop up window doesn't fit . how to reduce size for it? https://jsfiddle.net/vs6uzv50/12/

Comment: I don't really know what you mean. It works for me. Could you elaborate?

Comment: If I resize window to mobile view, timepicker window doesn't fit. It is not responsive.

Comment: This is also a problem with jsfiddle. Try it on a standalone site.